# const and let fake hoisting in modules

Tags: javascript, module, constants, let, hoisting

I've found interesting behaviour while having `let` and `const` on module level.

func.mjs

```
export const func = () => {
  return num1 + num2;
}

const num1 = 5;
const num2 = 6;
```

main.mjs

```
import {func} from 'func.mjs';

console.log(func())
```

If you run `node main.mjs`, you'll get `11` in console. I can explain that as all module level expressions defined and initialised on import step.

But is it falling under concepts of TDZ?

Comment: Why would it fail? `num1` and `num2` aren't accessed until you call `func()` in `console.log(func())`.

Comment: So basicly we have a small `runtimes` on each import. Where everything is initialized and we'r not falling under TDZ there bc of that.

Comment: I'm not an expert on modules, but this shouldn't have anything to do with modules. When you import a module, the file is executed from top to bottom just like it would [if you would would replace the import with the code itself](https://jsfiddle.net/8pc9mxar/) (without he `export` of course). First the function is declared, then the two variables, and then the function is being executed. Only at that point are `num1` and `num2` used, which is after they have been declared. If you call `func()` after it has been declared but before you declare those variables, the TDZ would kick in.